# Expected Maximum of Three Numbers that Sum to 1

Tags: uniform-distribution, expected-value

I've been working on a programming project on classification with 3 classes, and I'm interested in comparing my results to what I'd expect from pure noise. So I have the following question:

Let $X,Y,Z$ be uniformly distributed over $\{(x,y,z)\in [0,1]^3:x+y+z=1\}$. What is $E \max (X,Y,Z)$?

Thanks

Sorry for editing after the fact. I'm also interested in $E(-X \log ( X )-Y\log ( Y )-Z \log (Z))$

Comment: If you are already programming, one idea would be to simulate this, say, 100 000 times and take the average. That ought to be pretty close to the expectation, and it shouldn't take too long.

Comment: I'm not sure how to program a random triple that sums to one. I had the idea of taking U, V, W all uniform(0,1); and setting X=U/U+V+W, Y=V/U+V+W, Z=W/U+V+W. Unfortunately, that isn't uniform.

Also, I'm somewhat curious whether there's a closed-form answer.

Comment: Let $x,y\tilde{}U(0,1)$.  If $x+y\lt1$, then let $z=1-x-y$ otherwise replace with $1-x,1-y$, and again $z=1-x-y$

Comment: Your second expectation is simplified somewhat by the fact that expectation is linear, and everything is symmetric in $X, Y, Z$, so it becomes $3E(-X\log(X))$. @Empy2: `\sim` is the command you're looking for: $x, y\sim U(0,1)$. `\tilde` is for having a wavey accent on top of another symbol, and therefore it becomes too small and too high up.

Comment: I've been trying to think of a proof that Empy2's method does in fact produce a uniform distribution, but haven't been able to come up with one. You're sure it's right?

Also, I guess there's no closed form answer for either expectation? How about a closed form expression for the marginal density function of X?

Comment: The pdf for the maximum is a triangle with vertices $(1/3,0), (1/2,3),(1,0)$

Answer (score 2):

If $(X,Y,Z)$ is uniformly distributed in $T=\{(x,y,z)\in[0,1]^3 : x+y+z=1\}$, then $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed in $T'=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2 : x+y\leqslant 1\}$, and $Z=1-X-Y$ a.s., thus
$$\mathbb{E}f(X,Y,Z)=2\iint_{T'}f(x,y,1-x-y)\,dx\,dy.$$
A simplification by symmetry, $\mathbb{E}\max\{X,Y,Z\}=6\,\mathbb{E} Z[X\leqslant Y\leqslant Z]$, gives
$$\mathbb{E}\max\{X,Y,Z\}=12\iint_{T''}(1-x-y)\,dx\,dy,$$
where
$$T''=\{(x,y) : 0\leqslant x\leqslant y\leqslant 1-x-y\}=\{(x,y) : 0\leqslant x\leqslant y\leqslant(1-x)/2\}.$$
This is easily computed, giving $\color{blue}{\mathbb{E}\max\{X,Y,Z\}=11/18}$.

For $\mathbb{E}(-X\log X-Y\log Y-Z\log Z)=3\,\mathbb{E}(-X\log X)$ (as noted in comments),
$$\iint_{T'}(-x\log x)\,dx\,dy=\int_0^1x(1-x)(-\log x)\,dx=\Gamma(2)(2^{-2}-3^{-2})=\frac{5}{36}$$
which gives $\color{blue}{\mathbb{E}(-X\log X-Y\log Y-Z\log Z)=5/6}$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting "$X$, $Y$, $Z$ uniformly distributed over $S:=\bigl\{(x,y,z)\in[0,1]^3\bigm| x+y+z=1\bigr\}$" as uniformly distributed with respect to surface measure on the equilateral triangle $S$. This measure is proportional to the euclidean measure of the projection $S'$ of $S$ to the $(x,y)$-plane.

The three medians $x=y$, $y=z$, $z=x$ partition $S$ into six congruent parts corresponding to the order $\leq$ of $x$, $y$, $z$. It is sufficient to compute the expected value $E$ in the part $T\subset S$ corresponding to $y\leq x\leq z=1-x-y$. This part $T$ projects to the triangle
$$T'=\bigl\{(x,y)\bigm| 0\leq y\leq x, \ x\leq 1-x-y\bigr\}\subset S'\ .$$
The vertices of $T'$ are $(0,0)$, $({1\over2},0)$, $({1\over3},{1\over3})$.
On $T$ we have $$\max\{x,y,z\}=z=1-x-y\ .$$ We therefore obtain
$$E={\int_{T'}(1-x-y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)\over{\rm area}(T')}=\ldots={11\over18}\ .$$